# drawing multiple boxplots from imputed data in R

Tags: r, boxplot, ggplot2

I have an imputed dataset that I'm analysing, and I'm trying to draw boxplots, but I can't wrap my head around the proper procedure.

my data (a sample, original has 20 observations per imputation and 13 vars per group, all values range from 0 to 25):

```
.imp  .id   FTE_RM  FTE_PD  OMZ_RM  OMZ_PD
1     1     25      25      24      24
1     2     4       0       2       6
1     3     11      5       3       2
1     4     12      3       3       3
2     1     20      15      15      15
2     2     4       1       2       3
2     3     0       0       0       6
2     4     20      0       0       0
```

`.imp` signifies the imputation round, `.id` the identifer for each observartion.

I want to draw all the `FTE_*` variables in a single plot (and the `OMZ_* in another), but wonder what to do with all the imputations, can I just include all values? The imputated data now has 500 observations. With for instance an ANOVA I'd need to average the ANOVA results by 5 to get back to 20 observations. But is this needed for a boxplot as well, since I only deal with medians, means, max. and min.?

Such as:

```
data_melt <- melt(df[grep("^FTE_", colnames(df))])
ggplot(data_melt, aes(x=variable, y=value))+geom_boxplot()
```

I've played a couple of times with ggplot, but consider myself a complete newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to keep the identifier for .imp and .id after melting so rather put:

```
data_melt <- melt(df,c(".imp",".id"))
```

For completeness of the dataframe it probably helps to introduce a column that identifies the type - FTE vs. OMZ:

```
data_melt$type <- ifelse(grepl("FTE",data_melt$variable),"FTE","OMZ")
```

Having this data.frame you can, for example, facet on the type (alternatively you can just use a simple filter statement on `data_melt` to restrict to one type):

```
ggplot(data_melt, aes(x=variable, y=value))+geom_boxplot()+facet_wrap(~type,scales="free_x")
```

This would look like this.
EDIT: fixed the data mess-up

[image]

Comment: thanks, this looks very good! However, can I just include all data from the imputations? made edit to elaborate my point

Comment: The boxplots as specified above will bunch all the data points (i.e. for any .imp x .id combination there is one value). If you are referring to statistical procedure which ones are allowed to be included for correctness I cannot help you - if you have a desire to only show a subset (i.e. `.imp==1`) then filtering on data_melt works.

Comment: why are there points on the graph, I have them as well. I can't seem to find them...

Comment: nevermind. outliers. RTFM :/ 
I rewrote my question on Cross Validated as it is really a stats question. Thanks for the R help!